# Image not displaying full screen after reducing size of browser using carousel slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, carousel

I am using Bootstrap 3 and carousel slider. When I reduce the size of the browser there are gaps on the left and right side of the image (highlighted in the screenshot below).

How can I have the image take up the full screen after the browser resizes?

[image: Snapshot]